# How to create a JRuby app with GUI and package it?

Tags: java, ruby, user-interface

I'm diving into Ruby's world and I'm loving it.

Right now I'm trying to develop a simple application with some sort of GUI and then package it so it can run in any OS (with JRE installed).

What I've found so far:

- GUI
- JrubyFX: it's great because allows me to use JavaFX Editor to create the look and feel of the app (and then use the generated FXML in my project). The problem is, I can run the examples with >jruby  but I can't package it to distribute.
- Packaging
- Wrabler, rawr, and jruby-jarify, all of them gave me errors when trying to make a JAR file (mostly about files not found).

So, right now, I just need some direction (and examples if possible) about the best way to make a JRuby app with GUI (usigng FXML if possible) and that I can easily package (in a JAR I guess) and make it run in any computer with JRE installed.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 2):

[shoes](http://shoesrb.com/) (especially shoes 4) might fit your requirements. It runs on top of jruby (1.7+) and you can [make an app package](https://github.com/shoes/shoes4#packaging-a-shoes-app).

However, it does not work on top of FXML. shoes uses its own DSL:

```
Shoes.app {
  background white
  stack(margin: 8) {
    button "A bed of clams"
    button "A coalition of cheetahs"
    button "A gulp of swallows"
  }
}
```

produces the following window:

[image]

Comment: Thanks tessi for your answer, I've installed it and tried to run a sample which worked perfectly.

Now I'm trying to package it but it only generates a .shy file. How can I put it into an .exe or .dmg or .deb/.rpm?

Best regards

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not that experienced with shoes (just toyed around with it). I suggest to ask a new StackOverflow question (with [the shoes tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shoes)), or open an issue at [their bug tracker](https://github.com/shoes/shoes4/issues).

Comment: Packaging for shoes4 is work in progress and broken for shoes3 :) There is a separate tag for packaging in the shoes4 tracker though.